# trouble getting python up and running

Tags: python

I'm a newcomer to python. I just downloaded the 2.x version and am trying to write a simple 'Hello world' program in an editor, and run it in the interpreter. This is my code (what i have in IDLE):

```
#!C:\Python27\python.exe
#Filename: helloworld.py

print('Hello World')
```

This is what I run in the interpreter:

```
python helloworld.py
```

And this it the response i get:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Anyone know whats going on here? Please help.

**CLARIFICATION:**

I should add that the program runs on IDLE's *Run Module* command. It just does not work in Python's command line interpreter.

Comment: What's the whole traceback (the whole error)? That code should run fine.

Comment: @Blender--
File "<stdin>", line 1
 python helloworld.py

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: To experiment with Python 3 print function in 2.7, use: from __ future __ import print_function

Comment: What do you mean by `run in the interpreter`. Do you run it as `C:\> python helloworld.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a little googling and relooking at your error message made it clear why you are getting the error.

Are you by any chance running your program in the idle prompt? If it says `python helloworld.py` it means it is complaining about this line not any specific line within helloworld.py.

Just come out from idle (**what you are calling the Interpreter**) and run form the command prompt. You would not get that offending error.

Apart from what other's have said about the print statement, the shebang in your script is unnecessary (but not wrong) if you are running under windows. That line make sense in *nix like environment where the shell determines the interpreter from the first line of the script.

Just to summarize

If you see something like

```
>>> python helloworld.py
```

This is wrong. You cannot invoke python within IDLE.

You need to be in command prompt to run it like

```
C:\python helloworld.py
```

This is right

In fact you can run your original script without any modification. Just run it the right way

Note*** Some other's might have said print statement is not a function in Python 2.7 so that particulat syntax is wrong. This is partly correct

You have actually not invoked the print function. You have just Enclosed the string with paranthesis and that is Syntactically correct.

If you have problem with setting up Python and Running on Windows, you may start looking at couple of things

1. The [FAQ for Python on Windows](http://docs.python.org/faq/windows.html).
2. The Newbie Series Video Tutorial, [Running Python on XP](http://showmedo.com/videotutorials/series?name=pythonOzsvaldPyNewbieSeries)

Answer (score 1):

`print` isn't a function in Python 2.7. You would have to say `print "Hello world!"` instead.

Comment: Add the new code to your question and let's take another look at it.

Answer (score 1):

python 3.0 and 2.7 both support parens on print... Part of the later 2.x changes were increasing support for 3.x syntax to ease transition. Anyone saying that 2.7 can't have parens is just plain wrong, they both work.

Since your print is right, try deleting the shebang and whitespace above the print and see if it works then. Since you're expressly declaring the interpreter in command line when executing it, the shebang is unneeded (it's only used when you do something like "myScript.py" not "python myScript.py")

Comment: ...although in Python 2, the parentheses are not recognized as function parameter delimiters, they are simply enclosing an expression just like you can write `a = (b + c)` or `a = b + c`.

Comment: You assume I think something is wrong with the shebang itself... I'm testing for invalid whitespaces (hence the "and whitespace above the print")

Answer (score 0):

> It just does not work in Python's command line interpreter.

Python **does not have** a "command line interpreter". It has a Python interpreter. You don't feed it commands; you feed it Python code. So for example you could type `print("Hello, world!")` here.

`python helloworld.py` is a command. It is used at the **system** command line.

Assuming you are using some recent version of Windows: there should be an item labelled "Command Prompt" in your Start menu, or else search for 'cmd.exe'. Run that. Now you have a command prompt. The part before the blinking cursor is the "current working directory". You can use the `cd` command to navigate to the directory where your `.py` file is (`cd ..` to go up a directory; `cd name_of_directory` to go into a subdirectory), and **then** issue `python helloworld.py`. This tells Windows "run the program `python.exe` and pass it `helloworld.py` as an argument. A separate copy of Python is launched, and it automatically opens `helloworld.py` and runs it.

IDLE's "Run Module" command (menu item) does the same thing. IDLE is not Python; it's a separate program that talks to Python (`python.exe`) for you. This allows it to wrap the interpreter in a window with menu items and so forth, and give you another window to edit a `.py` file and then feed that to Python. You can also run `python` with no arguments from the command line (in the previous step); this will give you a Python interpreter prompt inside the Command Prompt window, where you can type single statements of Python code and run them. This is often useful for testing short snippets of code while you are writing a `.py` file.

Answer (score -2):

In python3

```
print("helloworld")
```

In python2.7

```
print "helloworld"
```